# Perform Action When Key is Pressed With Jquery?

Tags: jquery, keypress

I would like for an action to occur when I push the "1" key on my keyboard.    My code below does not seem to work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (code == 97) {
        alert("hello world");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have any key press handler there. Look for [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event

Comment: Read over the code again and try to understand what's going on here... First, there is no e in this context. Second, this code executes on document ready, not on a keypress event. Why would you expect it to run just because you pressed a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) handler on `document`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/95utv3v7/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    //            ^^^^^^^^
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 49) { // 1 is pressed
      alert("hello world!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this code into my script and nothing popped up when i pushed 1